# Having trouble grasping the class equation as an explanation as to why a conjugate class's order divides the order of a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $|G|$ is a prime power $p^n$ and that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
Show that $|y^G|$ is a power of $p$ whenever $y \in G$

Attempt:

Firstly, I assume that $y^G = \{ gyg^{-1} | g \in G \}$' i.e. we're talking about a  conjugacy class here. And I know I'm supposed to use the class equation and the fact that $N$ is a normal subgroup in $G$ but I just don't know how. I mean, I saw the [Wiki explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) for it but I just don't think I was able to follow the logic in a way I can absorb and repeat.

Could you show me how to answer this question and maybe explain how I can conceptualize conjugation classes in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|y^G|=[G:C_G(y)]$ by orbit stabilizer theorem and $C_G(y)$ denotes the stabilizer of $y$ in $G$.

Since $C_G(y)$ is a subgroup of $G$ its index is equal to a power of $p$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class

Comment: Thank you for the swift response! Is that all that's required? I tend to worry (despite advice not to) about answers being "too short"

Comment: @Siyanda: I want it to be clear, If you want to ask a point, I can expand it.